# Enzyme testing with React/Redux - shallow rendering issues with setState

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme

I have a React component that loads another component if it has it's initial local state altered. I can't get a clean test going because I need to set local state AND shallow render so the child component doesn't crash when the new component mounts because the redux store isn't there. It seems those two objectives are incompatible in Enzyme.

For the child component to display, things need to occur:

1. The component needs to receive a "response" props (any string will do)
2. The component need to have it's initial "started" local state updated to true. This is done with a button in the actual component.

This is creating some headaches with testing. Here is the actual line that determines what will be rendered:

```
let correctAnswer = this.props.response ? <div className="global-center"><h4 >{this.props.response}</h4><Score /></div> : <p className="quiz-p"><strong>QUESTION:</strong> {this.props.currentQuestion}</p>;
```

Here is my current Enzyme test:

```
it('displays score if response and usingQuiz prop give proper input', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Quiz usingQuiz={true} answers={[]} response={'example'}/>);  
    wrapper.setState({ started: true }) 
    expect(wrapper.contains(<Score />)).toEqual(true)
});
```

I am using shallow, because any time I use mount, I get this:

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Score)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Score)".
```

Because the  component is displayed through the parent, I can not simply select the disconnected version. Using shallow seems to correct this issue, but then I can not update the local state. When I tried this:

```
it('displays score if response and usingQuiz prop give proper input', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Quiz usingQuiz={true} answers={[]} response={'example'}/>);  
    wrapper.setState({ started: true })  
    expect(wrapper.contains(<Score />)).toEqual(true)
});
```

The test fails because shallow doesn't let the DOM get updated.

I need BOTH conditions to be met. I can do each condition individually, but when I need to BOTH 1) render a component inside a component (needs shallow or will freak about the store not being there), and 2) update local state (needs mount, not shallow), I can't get everything to work at once.

I've looked at chats about this topic, and it seems this is a legitimate limitation of Enzyme, at least in 2017. Has this issue been fixed? It's very difficult to test this.

Here is the full component if anyone needs it for reference:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Transition } from 'react-transition-group';  
import { answerQuiz, deleteSession, getNewQuestion  } from '../../actions/quiz'; 
import Score from '../Score/Score'; 
import './Quiz.css'; 

export class Quiz extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        // local state for local component changes
        this.state = {
            started: false
        }
    }

    handleStart() {
        this.setState({started: true})
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.props.dispatch(deleteSession(this.props.sessionId))
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.props.correctAnswer && this.props.continue) {
            this.props.dispatch(getNewQuestion(this.props.title, this.props.sessionId)); 
        }
        else if (this.props.continue) {
            const { answer } = this.form; 
            this.props.dispatch(answerQuiz(this.props.title, answer.value, this.props.sessionId)); 
        }
        else {
            this.props.dispatch(deleteSession(this.props.sessionId))
        }
    }

    render() {  

        // Transition styles
        const duration = 300; 
        const defaultStyle = {
            opacity: 0, 
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
            height: '100%', 
            width: '100%', 
            margin: '0px', 
            zIndex: 20, 
            top: '0px', 
            bottom: '0px', 
            left: '0px', 
            right: '0px', 
            position: 'fixed',
            display: 'flex', 
            alignItems: 'center', 
            transition: `opacity ${duration}ms ease-in-out`
        }

        const transitionStyles = {
            entering: { opacity: 0 }, 
            entered: { opacity: 1 }
        }

        // Response text colors
        const responseClasses = [];
        if (this.props.response) {
            if (this.props.response.includes("You're right!")) {
                responseClasses.push('quiz-right-response')
            }
            else {
                responseClasses.push('quiz-wrong-response');
            }
        }

        // Answer radio buttons
        let answers = this.props.answers.map((answer, idx) => (
            <div key={idx} className="quiz-question">
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value={answer} /> <span className="quiz-question-label">{answer}</span>
            </div>
        )); 

        // Question or answer
        let correctAnswer = this.props.response ? <div className="global-center"><h4 className={responseClasses.join(' ')}>{this.props.response}</h4><Score /></div>: <p className="quiz-p"><strong>QUESTION:</strong> {this.props.currentQuestion}</p>; 

        // Submit or next 
        let button = this.props.correctAnswer ? <button className="quiz-button-submit">Next</button> : <button className="quiz-button-submit">Submit</button>; 

        if(!this.props.continue) {
            button = <button className="quiz-button-submit">End</button>
        }

        // content - is quiz started? 
        let content; 
        if(this.state.started) {
            content = <div>
                <h2 className="quiz-title">{this.props.title} Quiz</h2>
                    { correctAnswer }
                    <form className="quiz-form" onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)} ref={form => this.form = form}>
                        { answers }
                        { button }
                    </form>
                </div>
        } else {
            content = <div>
                <h2 className="quiz-title">{this.props.title} Quiz</h2>
                <p className="quiz-p">So you think you know about {this.props.title}? This quiz contains {this.props.quizLength} questions that will test your knowledge.<br /><br />
                Good luck!</p>
                 <button className="quiz-button-start" onClick={() => this.handleStart()}>Start</button>
            </div>
        }

        // Is quiz activated? 
        if (this.props.usingQuiz) {
            return ( 
                <Transition in={true} timeout={duration} appear={true}>
                    {(state) => (
                            <div style={{ 
                                ...defaultStyle,
                                ...transitionStyles[state]
                    }}>
                    {/* <div className="quiz-backdrop"> */}
                        <div className="quiz-main">
                            <div className="quiz-close" onClick={() => this.handleClose()}>
                                <i className="fas fa-times quiz-close-icon"></i>
                            </div>
                            { content } 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
                </Transition >
            )  
        } 
        else {
            return <Redirect to="/" />; 
        }      
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    usingQuiz: state.currentQuestion, 
    answers: state.answers, 
    currentQuestion: state.currentQuestion, 
    title: state.currentQuiz,
    sessionId: state.sessionId,  
    correctAnswer: state.correctAnswer, 
    response: state.response,
    continue: state.continue, 
    quizLength: state.quizLength,
    score: state.score, 
    currentIndex: state.currentIndex
}); 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Quiz);
```

Here is my test using mount (this crashes due to a lack of store):

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { Quiz } from '../components/Quiz/Quiz';
import { Score } from '../components/Score/Score';  
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'; 

    it('displays score if response and usingQuiz prop give proper input', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<Quiz usingQuiz={true} answers={[]} response={'example'}/>);  
        wrapper.setState({ started: true })  
        expect(wrapper.contains(<Score />)).toEqual(true)
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a component that should be tested with `mount(..)`.

How are you importing your connected component `Score` and `Quiz`?

I see that you are already correctly exporting `Quiz` component and default exporting the connected `Quiz` component.

Try importing with

```
import { Score } from '../Score/Score';
import { Quiz } from '../Quiz/Quiz';
```

in your test, and `mount(..)`ing. If you are importing from default export, you will get a connected component imported, which I think is the cause of the error.

Comment: If I use mount with { Score }, I get this: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Score)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Score)".

Comment: Because the Score component is contained within the parent, it doesn't matter how I import it. It's getting it from within the component, which is the connected version. And that crashes it. I was shallow because that allows you to still check the presence of child components without this type of crashing. But that prevents any local state changes.

Comment: Did you try `render(..)`?

Comment: By the way, is it necessary that `Score` be a container component? Can you pass the necessary data and functions as props from `Quiz`?

Comment: render() and update() both cause the store crash. Again, this actually may be a limitation of the Enzyme library. I was looking into it and this seems to be a known issue

Comment: I have another similar test. This works: 
const wrapper = shallow(<NasaPhoto usingNasaPhoto={true} infoOn={true} />); 
        expect(wrapper.contains(<NasaPhotoInfo />)).toEqual(true);

Comment: But it works because I don't need to change local state to get the child.

Comment: Even though this is not a recommended approach, you can try mocking the store if it's necessary that `Score` be a container component.

Comment: You know, I ditched the whole local state bit. I was doing that to make it easier on the store, but it could also easily be handled by redux.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `Transition` component let it's content to be displayed? I use this component and can't properly handle it in tests...
Can you for the test purposes alter your `render`s `return` with something like this:

```
if (this.props.usingQuiz) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        this.state.started && this.props.response ?
        (<Score />) :
        (<p>No score</p>)
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

And your test can look something like this:

```
it('displays score if response and usingQuiz prop give proper input',() => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Quiz usingQuiz={true} answers={[]} response={'example'}/>);
  expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toBe('No score');
  wrapper.setState({ started: true });
  expect(wrapper.contains(<Score />)).toEqual(true);
});
```

I also tested `shallow`s `setState` and little test like this works fine:

```
test('HeaderComponent properly opens login popup', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<HeaderComponent />);
  expect(wrapper.find('.search-btn').text()).toBe('');
  wrapper.setState({ activeSearchModal: true });
  expect(wrapper.find('.search-btn').text()).toBe('Cancel');
});
```

So I believe that shallow properly handle `setState` and the problem caused by some components inside your `render`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because you're trying to test the wrapper component generated by calling `connect()()`. That wrapper component expects to have access to a Redux store. Normally that store is available as context.store, because at the top of your component hierarchy you'd have a `<Provider store={myStore} />`. However, you're rendering your connected component by itself, with no store, so it's throwing an error.

Also, if you are trying to test a component inside a component, may full DOM renderer may be the solution.

If you need to force the component to update, Enzyme has your back. It offers `update()` and if you call `update()` on a reference to a component that will force the component to re-render itself.